# declare variable of a type X in class X when defining my class X

Tags: c#, definition

I know that the title is not clear but sorry for my english I did not find how to formulate my question. So I hope below I could explain it further.

In fact I was reading a code where the user, when he was defining a class (let's called X), he declared a table of X (in the class definition).

Coming from C++, this is not possible as the type X is incomplete at that stage.

and another question : in the ctor the user allocate 10 elements so was thinking that it may be an infinite loop as for each instance of X we allow 10 elements which was not the case !

So does C# allow such behavior ?

```
//here we start the class definition
class X
{
    X[] Items = null;  // and here we declare a table of X elements ???

    public X()
    {
        Items = new X[10];  // and here we allocate 10 elements of X  ???
    }
}
```

Comment: It is fine to use the type of the class you are currently in. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Progman : I m not saying that it was a problem, but I came from C++ background and it is not possible to do such code : as you are defining a class, you cam't declare vars in that class with same type as it is incomplete.

Was just asking if C# does allow it.

beside that in the ctor the user allocate 10 elemets so was thinking that my be an infinite loop as for each instance we allow 10 ele;ents which was not the case

Comment: `new X[10]` creates an array for instances of the `X` class, it does not create any `X` instance.

Comment: if you think it feel to strange you might wanna consider an interface, like others say you can do this but going with an interface might feel less strange and might open up to more flexablility later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, there is no problem with incomplete types.

On the other hand, I see what you mean by infinite loop. But this is also not the case, because only the array is allocated (in C++ an array of pointers), so these pointers are all NULL, the default constructor is not called.